# postfix recipient_bcc_maps multiple recipients how to?

Tags: postfix-mta

is it ever possible to have multiple recipients in `/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps` ?

```
/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps :

source@domain.tld recipient1@domain.tld
```

Can I do something like:

`**source@domain.tld rcpt1@domain.tld,rcpt2.domain.tld,rcpt3@domain.tld**`

Googling with no success whatsoever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant specify multiple recipients in the right hand side of the `recipient_bcc_maps`. So

```
source@domain.tld    rcpt1@domain.tld,rcpt2.domain.tld,rcpt3@domain.tld
```

is not possible. But The BCC address is subject to virtual alias expansion (and aliases(5)
expansion for any resulting local recipients). So

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#...
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
#...

#/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
source@domain.tld    rcpt@domain.tld


#/etc/postfix/vmaps
rcpt@domain.tld    rcpt1@domain.tld,rcpt2.domain.tld,rcpt3@domain.tld
```

should help you to achieve it.

Ref: [Postfix Mailinglist](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.postfix.user/184977)

Comment: Thank you Clement! How did I miss this!

Comment: i dont understand this feature, why do i need to create/add second address just to copy emails to other addresses... hm

Comment: Unfortunately this is an incomplete solution, because virtualmaps and recipient_bcc_maps are NOT the same. The recipient_bcc_maps forwards the email leaving a copy in the original inbox (basically bcc-ing), while the virtual_maps does NOT. As such this is NOT a general solution to the problem of having multiple recipient_bcc_maps, only covers a specific scenario. To achieve that, you need to create a "dummy" alias in the virtual_maps, for which you don't care that no copy of the email is left.

Comment: Zoltan, you can put the original address in the result column of the virtual alias maps too. This will achieve what you want.